# Checking nvidia driver version with error "Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system"

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I tried to check my nvidia driver version using `sudo nvidia-smi`. However, i got an error `Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system`
Hope to get support from you on this issue.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It was happened because of installing a nvidia toolkit (I am not sure). According to [this website](https://github.com/Kaixhin/dockerfiles/issues/1) (which has useful ideas)
I found that cuda driver version in the cuda installer and host was incompatible. (host : 367.57 , installer: 375.26 , At first I could not check the installer version because all the versions was 367.57, but when I reinstall cuda by run file, I found it)

So, I uninstalled cuda and nvidia completely and install cuda again by [this help](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#axzz4aov3z8A4). At first in the installation process I got some errors which I found, nvidia has not completely gone. After uninstalling completely, I installed cuda and now I can run "sudo nvidia-smi" without problem.

Answer (score 0):

If rebooting the machine cannot be helped, you could easily overcome this problem by installing the latest version of CUDA.

```
sudo nvidia-installer --update
```

and check the status of GPU again.

```
nvidia-smi
```

Hope this help.